# Recursive call in JavaScript not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I have defined a function and calling it recursive and its not working 
here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//if i remove the slider call here it doesn't even run the function slider     
slider();
    function slider() {
        $("#img2").fadeOut(3000, function () {
            $("#img2").fadeIn(3000);
        });
//recursive call
        slider();
    }
});
```

Comment: How have you tried to debug this?

Comment: Your recursion never end,
Try console.log("something"); and see the result

Comment: You're calling `slider()` right after `.fadeOut`, but the first thing slider does is the `fadeOut` again. A fiddle or at least a description of what par of it isn't working would be nice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's working, but you call `slider()` again before the `fadeOut` has completed. Stick the recursive call in the callback:

```
function slider() {
    $("#img2").fadeOut(3000, function () {
        $("#img2").fadeIn(3000, function() {
            //As Kristof Feys pointed out, you probably want to wait for the 
            //fade in to complete, then call the method.
            slider();
        });
    });
}
```

A demo as well: http://jsfiddle.net/9k7e3/

Comment: Wouldn't he want to call it after the fadeIn has completed rather than the fadeOut?

Comment: @KristofFeys -- Very good point, let me add a callback to the `fadeIn`

Answer (score 2):

Its working just fine. You must remember the `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` function are asynchronous. Meaning, the browser does not wait until the animation is done before it executes the next line of code. So as a result, your `slider()` function is getting called thousands of times before the animation even completed one iteration.

If you look in the console, you will see this error being thrown:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Meaning you are calling the `slider` function too many times. The solution is to place the `slider()` call inside the `fadeIn` callback, which will be executed only once the animation is complete.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    slider();
    function slider() {
        $("#img2").fadeOut(3000, function () {
            $("#img2").fadeIn(3000, function(){
                slider();
            });
        });
    }
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mLQx/2/)